# Suggestions for OAuth2 libraries for integration with Jersey?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, oauth-2.0

I am working on making Jersey web services available using OAuth2 to other clients and am having a tough time finding libraries that tie in nicely with Jersey.  So far I have looked at the following libraries.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/support.html

We got the demo working, but do not want to use spring security.

https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/oauth2-framework/downloads

This is tied tightly to RESTLet.

http://wiki.apache.org/incubator/AmberProposal

We looked briefly, but it hard to tell the status of the project.

https://bitbucket.org/smartproject/oauth-2.0/wiki/Home

We just started looking at this one as well.

The main goal we have is simple integration with Jersey as a Resource Provider.

Comment: I've been playing with a checkout of Amber today and have the facebook client example working.  Right now I'm just working through the authorization server integration tests trying to put together a simple server to test with from some examples.  If anyone has a quick authorization example with Amber, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We ended up using Amber, modifying the endpoints from the integration tests as needed.

[oauth-2.0/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/oltu/oauth2/integration/endpoints/](https://github.com/apache/oltu/tree/trunk/oauth-2.0/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/oltu/oauth2/integration/endpoints/)

Comment: Looking back, was it a good choice? I'm facing this decision now.

Comment: I am happy enough with it, it works well where you need a standalone library without a whole lot of dependencies.