# Jersey + Oauth 2.0

Tags: spring, oauth, jersey

I'm working on the creation of a REST API using Jersey + Spring 3.0. Jersey is set up and is working correctly however I'm at the point where I need to add authentication to the service.

Initially I was asked to look into Oauth however I am considering Oauth 2.0 due to it (apparently) being quite a bit easier for end users to use.

So basically:
Is it possible to use with Jersey? Does anyone have any guides? Do any libraries exist (if they're even needed)?

Comment: Look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652146/suggestions-for-oauth2-libraries-for-integration-with-jersey I think it will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

We do support oauth 1.0 (both 2-legged and 3-legged). See com.sun.jersey.contribs.jersey-oauth group id on maven. I am not aware of any library specifically for OAuth 2.0 - OAuth 2.0 is still a work in progress.